# Continuous injective function that fails to map open sets to open sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, open-map

I'm studying metric spaces and have just proved that continuous maps preserve open sets under pre-image. The book I'm learning from says to beware of what this theorem does *not* say: that a continuous map sends the forward image of an open set to an open set.

I found these counterexamples:

1. any constant map $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. Since singletons are closed in $\mathbb{R}$ under usual metric.
2. $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$; $f(x)=x^2$, since $f((-1,1))=[0,1)$ but $[0,1)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Reflecting on these it seems that both fail to be injective. So I have been trying to find a continuous *injective* function that fails to map forward open sets to open sets but am at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: A continuous injection $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ does map open sets to open sets, so you'll need to consider different metric spaces.

Comment: A function that sends open sets to open sets is called an open mapping. A continuous injection that is an open mapping is a homeomorphism of the domain with its image. That lets you construct many examples, by mapping for example disconnected sets to connected sets or the like. For example, $f\colon (0,1)\cup\{2\}\to (0,1]$ which is the identity on $(0,1)$ and sends $2$ to $1$ is continuous , injective, but sends the open set $\{2\}$ to the non-open set $\{1\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$, $x\mapsto(x,0)$.

$\Bbb R$ is open in $\Bbb R$ but $f(\Bbb R)$ is not open in $\Bbb R^2$, and $f$ is certainly a continuous injection (be careful: if you change the domain to $\Bbb R\times\{0\}$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R^2$, then $f$ *is* open!)

N.B. If you only deal with Euclidean spaces, you will find no counterexamples where $f:A\to B$ has $A$ a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R^n$ for compactness reasons. You can use reasoning like this to deduce Eric's comment that any continuous injection $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is also open.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S^1=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2=1\}$ and take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,2\pi)&\longrightarrow&S^1\\&\theta&\mapsto&(\cos\theta,\sin\theta).\end{array}$$Then $f$ is bijective and continuous, but it maps the open subset $[0,\pi)$ of $[0,2\pi)$ onto $\{(x,y)\in S^1\mid y\geqslant0\}\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$, which is not an open subset of $S^1$.

Comment: I like your hat sir

Comment: @FShrike I chose it because it matches the color of my eyes.

Comment: Sorry but do you mean $S^1$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the last line?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that.